# Unable to access ESXi-7 with web client

Tags: vmware, vsphere, esxi, vmware-workstation

After installing VMware ESXi 7 with VMware Workstation, I can't access it from web client from the displayed IP.
[image]

[image]

This is my IPv4 configuration.[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you ping it? If not, what is your networking configuration in VMware Workstation? If yes, check your Windows firewall. If it's on, check those logs to ensure it's not blocking the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Try to ping your ESXi, check your network configuration gateway and IP address.

How did you configure vmware workstation ? I guess your issue come from your network configuration on vmware workstation.

This documentation may help you to choose the right network to use on Vmware Workstation for your need. https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Player-for-Windows/16.0/com.vmware.player.win.using.doc/GUID-C82DCB68-2EFA-460A-A765-37225883337D.html

Answer (score 0):

Add `https://` before the IP address.